# ¿Cómo eliminar valores repetidos, columna por columna, sin eliminar toda la fila?

Tags: base-de-datos, r, dataframe

Tengo un dataframe con la siguiente estructura:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En rownames aparece el nombre de una especie y en las columnas V´s aparece su sinónimo. El dataframe tiene esta forma porque la función que se utilizó para crearla llena automáticamente los espacios de todas las especies de acuerdo con el mayor número de sinónimos que encuentre. Es decir, en este caso la especie *Acanthocelys radiolata* tiene cuatro sinónimos diferentes y por esta razón todas las especies del dataframe aparecen con 4 sinónimos, pero vemos que algunos se repiten. Si alguna especie tuviera 30 sinónimos, la tabla tendría 30 columnas con valores repetidos. Mi pregunta para la comunidad sería la siguiente:

1. ¿Cómo puedo vaciar (null) las celdas repetidas por cada especie, de tal manera que me aparezcan el o los sinónimos de cada especie sin repetir. Por ejemplo que para la primera especie me aparezca (Edodonta constricta, NULL, NULL, NULL), para la segunda especie me aparezca (Helix fuscozonata, Patula fuscozonata, NULL, NULL), etc.

Agradezco muchísimo cualquier ayuda. Si de pronto es de alguna ayuda, la función utilizada para construir el dataframe (sinonimos_mtx) es la siguiente:

```
sinonimos = list()
for (i in species)
  {
  sinonimos[[i]] = rl_synonyms(i, API)[[3]] 
  }
sinonimos_mtx <- do.call(rbind, lapply(sinonimos, "[[", "synonym")) # Class 'matrix''array'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imaginando una estructura similar a la tuya:

```
set.seed(2021)
df <- data.frame(V1 = sample(LETTERS[1:4], 4, replace = TRUE),
                 V2 = sample(LETTERS[1:4], 4, replace = TRUE),
                 V3 = sample(LETTERS[1:4], 4, replace = TRUE),
                 V4 = sample(LETTERS[1:4], 4, replace = TRUE))

rownames(df) <- paste0("fila-", 1:4)
df

       V1 V2 V3 V4
fila-1  A  D  A  B
fila-2  C  B  C  D
fila-3  D  C  B  A
fila-4  C  D  D  B
```

---

Y si no te preocupa mantener el orden de aparición, podrías aplicar `unique()` a cada fila y completar con `NA`:

```
m <- t(apply(df, 1, FUN = function(x){u <- unique(x); c(u, rep(NA, length(x) - length(u)))}))
as.data.frame(do.call(rbind,list(m)))

       V1 V2 V3   V4
fila-1  A  D  B <NA>
fila-2  C  B  D <NA>
fila-3  D  C  B    A
fila-4  C  D  B <NA>
```